# Postfix - virtual mailbox - exclude addresses from wildcard coverage

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-10.04, wildcard

are there syntax elements or another way to exclude one or more mailadresses from a wildcard in the virtual mailbox configuration of postfix?

My current working configuration is `/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox`:

```
me@example.com              example.com/me/
@example.com                example.com/me/

foo@example.com             example.com/foo/
bar@example.com             example.com/bar/
```

i added two users: `foo` & `bar`, but i will still receive their mails due to the wildcard `@example.com`. Is it possible to exclude `foo@example.com` & `bar@example.com` -mails from beeing delivered to my mailbox?

I would like to stay with the wildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As according to the postfix documentation, catchalls are by definition recursive

> VIRTUAL(5) VIRTUAL(5)
>   NAME
>   virtual - Postfix virtual alias table format
>
> SYNOPSIS
>   postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
>
> postmap -q "string" /etc/postfix/virtual
>
> postmap -q - /etc/postfix/virtual
>
> DESCRIPTION
>   The optional virtual(5) alias table rewrites recipient addresses for
>   all local, all virtual, and all remote mail destinations. This is
>   unlike the aliases(5) table which is used only for local(8) delivery.
>   **Virtual aliasing is recursive**

So, the solution is to create 1 to 1 mappings (to stop the recursion) for your actual users. In your virtual users file, you'd put things like this:

`foo@example.com   foo@example.com`
`bar@example.com   bar@example.com`

Comment: Wow, thats a simpler solution. I tought we would end up using regex :)
Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: wow, after googling for a while, I cannot believe it is that simple. many, many thanks, Nick!